# Checkbox datatable selected row

Tags: java, checkbox, datatable, primefaces

I have Checkbox datatable, first column is Checkbox, second and other outputtext but last column is inputtext(password) and this column `disabled="false"`, now I want if I click the checkbox this column change `disabled="true"`, how I can solve this?

```
<h:body>

        <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{regularityController.stlist}" paginator="true" rows="10"  rowKey="#{car.g_student_no}"
                     selection="#{regularityController.select}" >  

        <f:facet name="header">  
            Telebeleri secin  
        </f:facet>  

            <p:column  selectionMode="multiple" style="width:18px" />  

        <p:column headerText="Name">  
           <h:outputText value="#{car.s_name}" />   
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="Surname" >  
           <h:outputText value="#{car.s_surname}  " />  
        </p:column>  
        <p:column headerText="Father Name">

           <h:outputText value="#{car.s_fname}  " />

        </p:column>   

        <p:column headerText="Father Name">

            <p:password disabled="#" value="#{car.s_pass }"/> 

        </p:column>   

        <f:facet name="footer">  
            <p:commandButton value="ddd" action="#{regularityController.saveStudent()}"/>  
        </f:facet>  
    </p:dataTable>  
    </h:body>
```

Comment: do you tried with javascript onclick="document.getElementById('#{p:component('idoftheinputtext')}').disabled=true"?

Answer (score 0):

do you tried with javascript: 
add to checkbox

```
    onclick="document.getElementById('#{p:component('id')}').disabled=true"
```

add an `id` to `password`